# MYSQL Workbench fails to update index sort order

Tags: mysql, database

I have tried to edit the indexes on my database.
But everytime i apply and press finish the result is the same when reopening the index editor
Do i have to set a specific set of parameters for this to work?
Or does innoDb not allow btree indexes in descending order?

Comment: Which version of MySQL Workbench are you using? In which OS? It sounds like a bug.